# Class 'Form' not found laravel 6.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have started a project with Laravel 6.4 but getting form error with 6.4 version I have checked some relevant solutions but none of them worked with this version.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you just need to do `composer require laravelcollective/html` and `use Form` in Laravel 6.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not come with any Form/Html Building package. You are looking for `laravelcollective/html`.

[LaravelCollective - HTML - Docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html)

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't work

Comment: what "doesn't work", what does that mean?

Comment: There was issue with my PHP version. Thanks for help